# How get position of item selected in a dialogfragment with radiobutton?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, android-radiobutton

I m developing DialogFragment with radiobuttons. Only I can select one option. I am using a ArrayAdapter to customize my DialogFragment.

[image: My Dialog Fragment]

I want to show , for example, the email of the selected option ( in this case alberto@gmail.com) when I press OK. My problem is that I cant getting the selected option.

**MYDIALOGFRAGMENT**

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final List<PlayerMVP> listPlayer= new ArrayList<PlayerMVP>();
        final PlayerMVPAdapter playerMVPAdapter = new PlayerMVPAdapter(getContext(),listPlayer);
        String gameID= getArguments().getString("gameID");
        Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame(gameID, getContext(), listPlayer, playerMVPAdapter);

        builder.setTitle("VOTA MVP");
        builder.setAdapter(playerMVPAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });


        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(playerMVPAdapter, 0, null).
                setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

   // Show email here

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);

        return builder.create();

    }
```

Here, I put also the code of getView of ArrayAdapter

**MYARRAYADAPTER- GET VIEW**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.playermvp,
                    parent,
                    false);

        }


        TextView nameAndSurname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nameAndSurnameMVP);
        TextView email= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email_mvp);
        final RadioButton rbFolder = (RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_MVP);

        rbFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selected != null) {
                    selected.setChecked(false);
                }

                rbFolder.setChecked(true);
                selected = rbFolder;
            }
        });

        PlayerMVP playerMVP= getItem(position);

        nameAndSurname.setText(playerMVP.getNombre() +' ' +playerMVP.getApellidos());
        email.setText(playerMVP.getEmail());

        return convertView;

    }
```

Thanks for you help!